# WSO2_EMM: which IP I should set when working in a testing environment

Tags: ip, wso2, wso2-iot

I would like to configure wso2-emm as a MAM and MDM, first I would like to work in  a testing environment, my laptop as a server and my android phone as a client, how should I set server IP in this case, and which IP I can assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any private IP address. But make sure to assign a static IP address if you configure iOS or Android with HTTPS, or every time you will need to configure it if your IP get changed.

Also make sure your server and device is connected with each other and necessary ports are opened in your network.

I am using small wifi router and and it is working fine.